# Reading from pdf file to text yields no results

Tags: python, pdf, text, filereader, pypdf

So I'm trying something very simple: I just want to read text from a pdf file in to a variable - that's it. This is what I'm getting:

[image]

Does anyone know a reliable way to just read pdf in to a text file?

Comment: Without further knowledge of the libraries you're using: Does your pdf contain text? Sometimes it's just images that look like text

Comment: I'm using PyPDF2

Comment: "So I'm trying something very simple" - that's not simple at all, and without a PDF file example, all anybody can do is guess. Please don't be that person that makes people guess - post a PDF sample file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following library - pdfplumber:

```
import pdfplumber
pdf_file = pdfplumber.open('anyfile.pdf')
page = pdf_file.pages[0]
text = page.extract_text()
print(text)
pdf_file.close()
```

I haven't used PyPDF2 before but pdfplumber seems to work well for me.

Comment: Can you share the PDF file? Or at least 1 page of the file?